# Record Types in Json Files

Tags: json, salesforcedx

I'm trying to import data into a new scratch org using Json files. I'm running into trouble trying to import records with the record types. An example of how it currently looks in my file:

```
    {
        "attributes": {
            "type": "LPiPES__Sacrament__c",
            "referenceId": "LPiPES__Sacrament__cRef11",
            "RecordType.DeveloperName": "First_Holy_Communion"
        },
        "LPiPES__Name__c": "@ContactRef11",
        "LPiPES__Date__c": "1983-05-06",
        "LPiPES__Place__c": "Beaver, WI",
        "LPiPES__Priest__c": "Father Benny",
        "LPiPES__Book_number__c": 15,
        "LPiPES__Page_number__c": 304,
        "LPiPES__Line_number__c": 401,
        "LPiPES__Date_of_Baptism__c": "1976-09-30",
        "LPiPES__Place_of_Baptism__c": "Waukesha, WI"
```

It's pulling all the correct fields in, but I can't seem to make the record type stick. Any suggestions?

Comment: Is that record type available in the profile you are using to import the data?

Comment: Yes it's available. I'm using the System Administrator profile to import the data.

Comment: There's a mention about record types not working in the last comment on this [question here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/199365/sfdx-how-to-export-data-with-record-types-to-put-in-a-scratch-qa-org) -- *Unfortunately, record types don't work in data:tree:export/import.* Possibly it still does not work.