# How to export import JSON data for objects with record types using sfdx command

Tags: salesforcedx, json, data-loader, salesforcedx-cli, sfdx-plugin

I wanted to export the objects data with record types from one scratch org to another scratch org.
I tried with this command:

```bash
> sfdx force:data:tree:export -q c:/soql/cObject.soql -u SourceOrg -p -d OutputPath
```

In the soql for the query, I attempt to get recordtype for each record using `RecordType.DeveloperName` in the `SELECT` clause.

I received the data with RecordType Name but when attempting to import the same json, it says *RecordType is not valid*. Here is the exact error:

> ERROR running force:data:tree:import:  {"hasErrors":true,"results":[{"referenceId":"cObject__cRef1","errors":[{"statusCode":"INVALID_FIELD","message":"Cannot reference a foreign key field RecordType.","fields":[]}]}]}**

Can you please let me know what mistake I did here.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SFDX -How to Export data with record types to put in a scratch / qa org](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/199365/sfdx-how-to-export-data-with-record-types-to-put-in-a-scratch-qa-org)(see comments, appears it is not possible)

Comment: The answer is not working at all. I need for Import as well

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `force:data:tree:export`, but [Salesforce Data Move Utility](https://help.sfdmu.com/) , authored by Salesforce.

The `export.json` file is simple to build, all you need is to write a request, and export then import goes well, even if there are record types, dependencies....

The `export.json` file for your case could be the following:

```json
    {
        "objects": [
            {
                "query": "SELECT all FROM YourObject__c",
                "operation": "Upsert",
                "externalId": "Name"
            }
        ]
    }
```

If you have a unique key different from `Name`, you can use composite external Id keys, like explained [here](https://help.sfdmu.com/full-documentation/advanced-features/composite-external-id-keys).

If you want an assisted use of SFDMU, you can also use [VsCode Sfdx Hardis](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=NicolasVuillamy.vscode-sfdx-hardis) UI (disclaimer: my company authors this open-source plugin), which contains a *Data Import/Export* menu.

[image]